# How to pass a prop to a component that is returned based on state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to return a component based on a parameter that was passed on a onClick handler `this.showComponentToRender('features')`. If features is clicked, it runs the `showComponentToRender(name)` and sets the state and in the `render()`, the `{this.state.showComponent}` shows the proper component.

However, a problem surfaces when I attempt to pass a prop `resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures}` within the

```
showFeatures() {
    return (<FeaturesList
             updateCad={this.props.updateCad}
             resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures}
           />);
  }
```

Clicking on the RESET A4 link, calls the `resetCrossbow()` which activates a function in the parent component. The parent component updates its state, and passes the state as a prop to its child.

For some reason, I can not get the resetFeatures prop to come into the `<FeaturesList />` component if I return it within a function that gets set in state. Why is this? I am looking for suggestions to fix.

If I do the traditional method of placing the `<FeaturesList />` within the return of the `render()`, all is well.

**Here's the component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FeaturesList from  './FeaturesList';
import ColorsList from './ColorsList';
import './../assets/css/features-menu.css';

export default class FeaturesMenu extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showComponent: this.showFeatures()
    };

    this.showFeatures = this.showFeatures.bind(this);
    this.showColors = this.showColors.bind(this);
  }

  showFeatures() {
    return (<FeaturesList
             updateCad={this.props.updateCad}
             resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures}
           />);
  }

  showColors() {
    this.props.resetCrossbow();
    return <ColorsList switchColor={this.props.switchColor} />
  }

  showComponentToRender(name) {
    if (name === 'features') {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: this.showFeatures()
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: this.showColors()
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(`this.props.resetFeatures: ${this.props.resetFeatures}`);

    return (
      <div id="features-menu-wrapper">
        <nav id="features-menu">
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('features')}>FEATURES</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('colors')}>COLORS</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.props.resetCrossbow()}>RESET A4</li>
        </nav>

        <div id="component-wrapper">
          {this.state.showComponent} // <- I am not able to pass resetFeatures prop if I do it this way. Why?

          {/* <FeaturesList
             updateCad={this.props.updateCad}
             resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures} <- I am able to pass resetFeatures prop as normal.
           />
          <ColorsList switchColor={this.props.switchColor} /> */}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `{this.state.showComponent}` has been already rendered. So you can't change their props there. You can create some kind of HOC and use it to pass additional props to the `showComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve results is pass additional properties to render specific components function and use spread to pass these props to the rendered component:

```js
   
const FeaturesList = ({additional = 'Empty'} = {}) => <div>Feature List with additional prop <b>{additional}</b></div>
const ColorsList = ({additional = 'Empty'} = {}) => <div>Colors List with additional prop <b>{additional}</b></div>

class FeaturesMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showComponent: this.showFeatures({additional: 'Initial features'})
    };

    this.showFeatures = this.showFeatures.bind(this);
    this.showColors = this.showColors.bind(this);
  }

  showFeatures(props) {
    return (<FeaturesList
             updateCad={this.props.updateCad}
             resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures}
             {...props}
           />);
  }

  showColors(props) {
    this.props.resetCrossbow();
    return <ColorsList switchColor={this.props.switchColor} {...props} />
  }

  showComponentToRender(name) {
    if (name === 'features') {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: this.showFeatures({additional: 'features adds'})
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: this.showColors({additional: 'colors adds'})
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="features-menu-wrapper">
        <nav id="features-menu">
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('features')}>FEATURES</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('colors')}>COLORS</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.props.resetCrossbow()}>RESET A4</li>
        </nav>

        <div id="component-wrapper">
          {this.state.showComponent}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const props = {
  resetCrossbow: () => null,
  switchColor: () => null,
  updateCad: () => null,
  resetFeatures: () => null
}

ReactDOM.render(<FeaturesMenu {...props}/>, document.querySelector('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<root/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not save the entire component in your state. Just set a string related to it and as the value changes, the `FeaturesMenu` will react and 
call the function to render the correct component. Obviously, this code can be changed, but I think I've made my point. =)

```js
const FeaturesList = props => (<div>Features List</div>);
const ColorsList = props => (<div>Colors List</div>);

class FeaturesMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentComponent: 'Features'
    };

    this.showFeatures = this.showFeatures.bind(this);
    this.showColors = this.showColors.bind(this);
  }

  showFeatures() {
    return (<FeaturesList
             updateCad={this.props.updateCad}
             resetFeatures={this.props.resetFeatures}
           />);
  }

  showColors() {
    this.props.resetCrossbow();
    return <ColorsList switchColor={this.props.switchColor} />
  }

  showComponentToRender(name) {
    this.setState({ currentComponent: name })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="features-menu-wrapper">
        <nav id="features-menu">
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('Features')}>FEATURES</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.showComponentToRender('Colors')}>COLORS</li>
          <li onClick={() => this.props.resetCrossbow()}>RESET A4</li>
        </nav>

        <div id="component-wrapper">
          {this[`show${this.state.currentComponent}`]()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

// for testing purposes
const props = {
  resetCrossbow: () => {},
  switchColor: () => {},
  updateCad: () => {},
  resetFeatures: () => {}
}

ReactDOM.render(<FeaturesMenu {...props}/>, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main/>
```